# Substring between 2 indexes using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I started learning Java, currently I'm playing around with recursion.

I wanted to try and make a substring method which will substring from both sides by 1 character until we get the desired string.

I managed to do the first part but I'm having problem figuring out how to substring from the back.

`n` and `m` should be the indexes between which we want to substring (inclusive).

In this example result of method should be "bstri"

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "substringme";

    System.out.println(rec(s,2,6));
}

public static String rec(String s, int n, int m) {
    if(n == 0 /* && missing 2nd part of condition */){
        return s;
    } else {
        if(n>0){
            s = s.substring(1);
            n--;  
        }
        if(/* missing condition */){
            s= s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        }
        return rec(s,n,m);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So fixing your recursive method is fairly easy. We just do exactly the same as you did for `n`:

```
public static String rec(String s, int n, int m) {        
    if (n == 0 && m == 0) { 
        return s;
    }
    else {
        if(n > 0) {
            s = s.substring(1);
            n--;
        }
        if(m > 0) {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
            m--;
        }
        return rec(s,n,m);
    }
}
```

The issue now is that the value of `m` given as input is measured from the start of the String and it would be way more convenient for us if it were measured from the end of the String.

We can introduce a new method to do this for us which acts as our entry point to the recursive method:

```
public static String substr(String s, int n, int m) {
    final int newM = s.length() - m - 1; //-1 to be inclusive of the char
    return rec(s, n, newM);
}
```

You would then change your main method to call `substr()` instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "substringme";

    System.out.println(substr(s,2,6));
}
```

I often find myself writing these kind of "entry point" methods when I'm using recursive methods. If you were doing this properly, `substr` would be your public-facing method and `rec` would be private.

Comment: Huge thanks man, this helped a lot, I realized at some point that I need addition method but didn't have idea of how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I propose that you do `m--` in the first loop because the definition of m as an index changes when you shorten `s` from the front.

```
 public static String rec(String s, int n, int m) {
         if(n == 0 && m == s.length() - 1){
             return s;
         } else {
             if (n > 0) {
                 s = s.substring(1);
                 n--;
                 m--;
             }
             if (m < s.length() - 1) {
                 s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
             }
             return rec(s, n, m);
         }
     }
```

Comment: This is quite clever but I feel perhaps less idiomatic than what I proposed.

Comment: Totally, actually I saw your solution after and thought it was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Thanks this work too so you got upvote and answer too, I used Michael answer as I liked that separate method approach more(want to use it for some methods in future) but great job with making code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is look for the difference between m and the length of the string, and cut off characters from the end of the string until it is the correct length.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "substringme";
        System.out.println(rec(s,2,6));
    }

    public static String rec(String s, int n, int m) {
        if(n == 0 && s.length()-m < 1){
            return s;
        } else {

            if(s.length()-m > 1){
                s= s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
            }
            else if(n>0){
                s = s.substring(1);
                n--;  
            }
            return rec(s,n,m);
        }
    }
}
```

Also shouldn't substring from 2 to 6 be "bstr", not "bstri"?

```
System.out.println(s.substring(2, 6)); //equals bstr
```

Comment: I believe a traditional `substr` is inclusive for the first index and exclusive of the second index. He wanted a `substr` inclusive of both indexes.

Comment: It should be bstri because index 2 of string is 'b', index 6 of is 'i'
I didn't want copy of substring but wanted it to work inclusive to first and last index
Thanks for helping me out anyway.